# Join two dataframes on one column that contains substring of other

Tags: r, dataframe, fuzzyjoin

I am trying to left-join `df2` onto `df1`.

`df1` is my dataframe of interest, `df2` contains additional information I need.

Example:

```
#df of interest onto which the other should be joined
key1 <- c("London", "Paris", "Berlin", "Delhi") 
other_stuff <- c("Tea", "Coffee", "Beer", "Tea") 
df1 <- data.frame(key1, other_stuff)

#additional info df
key2 <- c("London and other cities", "some other city", "Eastberlin is history", "Berlin", "Delia is a name", "Delhi is a place") 
more_info <- c("history", "languages", "trades", "art", "commerce", "manufacturing")
df2 <- data.frame(key2,more_info)
```

What I now want is that `df2$key2` is searched for the precise occurrence of `df1$key1` and then merged onto `df1` (e.g. match Berlin to Berlin, but not to Eastberlin, and Delhi to Delhi but not to Delia) while ignoring the other words surrounding the match.

Desired outcome:

| key1 | other_stuff | more_info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Tea | history |
| Paris | Coffee | NA |
| Berlin | Beer | art |
| Delhi | Tea | manufacturing |

I tried variations of regex_left_join
`joined<- regex_left_join(df1,df2, by = c("key1" = "key2"),  ignore_case= F)`

and fuzzyjoins
`joined<- df1%>% fuzzy_left_join(df2, by = c("key1" = "key2"), match_fun = str_detect)`

They both only give a result for the exact match (key1=key2=Berlin) and give NA for everything else.

How do I do this?

I also tried [Merging two tables where one column is substring of the other in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637189/merging-two-tables-where-one-column-is-substring-of-the-other-in-r) but the logic in the SQL there is the wrong way around. I tried several other Stackexchange approaches, but they are "too fuzzy" for my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use the "regular" `dplyr::left_join`, but performed some selection in `df2` when joining it with `df1`.

First create a vector that contains your target city. Then I will split `df2$key2` by white space, and see if there is any word that matches the strings in the vector `city`. Then `left_join` it with `df1`.

```
library(tidyverse)

city <- c("London", "Paris", "Berlin", "Delhi")

left_join(df1,
          df2 %>% mutate(city = sapply(strsplit(df2$key2, " "), 
                                       function(x) first(intersect(city, x)))),
          by = c("key1" = "city")) %>% 
  select(-key2)

    key1 other_stuff     more_info
1 London         Tea       history
2  Paris      Coffee          <NA>
3 Berlin        Beer           art
4  Delhi         Tea manufacturing
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however, it gives me the following error message:

"Error in (function (cond) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'select': Problem with `mutate()` column `city`.
i `city = sapply(...)`.
x unable to find an inherited method for function ‘first’ for signature ‘"character"’
Caused by error:
! unable to find an inherited method for function ‘first’ for signature ‘"character"’ "

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, try importing all functions from `dplyr` (e.g. `dplyr::first`)

Answer (score 0):

The following works with the posted data examples but it uses two joins and is probably ineffective for larger data sets.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

left_join(
  df1,
  regex_left_join(df2, df1, by = c(key2 = "key1"))[c(3, 4, 2)] |> na.omit()
)
#> Joining, by = c("key1", "other_stuff")
#>     key1 other_stuff     more_info
#> 1 London         Tea       history
#> 2  Paris      Coffee          <NA>
#> 3 Berlin        Beer           art
#> 4  Delhi         Tea manufacturing
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the expected result because those functions passes the **second** dataframe as the regex pattern, so instead you could use `regex_right_join` or `fuzzy_right_join`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  regex_right_join(df2, ., by = c(key2 = "key1")) %>% 
  select(key1, other_stuff, more_info)

df1 %>% 
  fuzzy_right_join(df2, ., by = c(key2 = "key1"), match_fun = str_detect) %>% 
  select(key1, other_stuff, more_info)
```

---

output

```r
    key1 other_stuff     more_info
1 London         Tea       history
2  Paris      Coffee          <NA>
3 Berlin        Beer           art
4  Delhi         Tea manufacturing
```